# how to get bitmap from canvas (no setBitmap)

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

now,I want to get bitmap at ViewGroup 's dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas)  ;  only  know Canvas  have  CanvasFinalizerm and NativeCanvasWrapper .this maybe transform to bitmap  , I hope you may tell me how transform  or how get
this is my code

```
@Override
protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
    //canvas get a bitmap  so I copy and  change to draw
    paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
    canvas.drawCircle(getMeasuredWidth() / 2, getMeasuredHeight() / 2, getMeasuredWidth() / 2, paint);

}
```

Comment: @MikeM. and yet you can get the rabbit out of a hat, how about that?

Comment: @MikeM. now is so,but I hope who can make a method to get Bitmap .I think everything is possible.but i don't understand jni ...

Comment: Clarify exactly what you're trying to accomplish. There's probably a better way to do it. At the point when `dispatchDraw()` is called, the `ViewGroup` has only drawn itself, so I don't see why you'd need that specific `Bitmap`, really.

Comment: @MikeM. So,I tell you I will make a blur effect .if i use it .you will look that viewGroup 's all childs blur.you can recurrence child and blur ;but maybe cause OOM. so I think  dispatchDraw ;look me top code ,you maybe know my reason.